# The connection between 'System.out.println()' and 'toString()' in Java

Tags: java, class, overriding, tostring

What is the connection between `System.out.println()` and `toString()` in Java? e.g:

```
public class A {
    String x = "abc";

    public String toString() {
        return x;
    }
}

public class ADemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

If main class runs, it gives an output as `"abc"`. When I remove the code which overrides `toString()`, it gives an output as `"A@659e0bfd"`. So, can anyone explain what is the working principle of `System.out.println()` when I pass the `obj` object reference as an argument to it? Is it fully connected with `toString()` method?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`System.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). Printstream defines several versions of the `println()` function to handle numbers, strings, and so on. When you call `PrintStream.println()` with an arbitrary object as a parameter, you get [the version of the function that acts on an `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)). This version of the function

> ...calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value...

Looking at [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)), we see that it returns

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

So, long story short, `System.out.println(someObject)` calls that object's `toString()` function to convert the object to a string representation.

If your object defines its own `toString()` function, then that is what will be called. If you don't provide such a function, then your object will inherit `toString()` from one of its parent classes. In the worst case, it will inherit [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). That version of toString() is defined to return

> a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

Or, in other words:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

So, when you call `System.out.println()` on an object that doesn't define its own version of toString(), you might get the `Object` version which looks like "classname@someHexNumber".

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` is a method that exist in the `Object` class (Root of the inheritence tree) for all classes.

`System.out.print()` (SOP) will call the toString method when fed an object.

If you don't overwrite the method `toString()`, SOP will call the parent `toString()` which, if parent is the Object class, it will print the hashCode of the object

If you overwrite the method, SOP will call your `toString()` method

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(obj) will print the returned string from obj.toString() if you dont override it it will call the base object.toString() method which by default the toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```