# Can any body explain me how toString() method in the following program is working?

Tags: java

Can any body explain me how toString() method in the following program is working?In the below program I didn't call the toString() method.But how the message is being printed when I create an Object can any one explain me.I am new to java.

```
class Inner
    {
       public String toString()
       {
         return "Hai this is java";
       }
    }

class Main
{
   public static void main(String [] java)
   {
      System.out.println(new Inner());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` returns a `PrintStream` instance. `PrintStream` has a `public void println(Object x)` method which calls `String.valueOf(x)` for the `Object` passed to it. `String.valueOf(x)` calls the object's `toString()` method when you pass to it a non null reference.

Comment: This question is a total duplicate of [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318996/the-connection-between-system-out-println-and-tostring-in-java), and you should closed it.

Comment: public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    } // I understood how it will work but why synchronized is used here

Comment: Here what is synchronized(this)?

Comment: @CSiva You should Google the `synchronized` reserved word. It is used to synchronize access to an object. In this case, the object is the `PrintStream` instance. If two threads attempt to write to the same `PrintStream` instance at the same time, one will have to wait until the other is done.

Answer (score 0):

The print command will always print the value returned by the toString method of the object you pass as parameter.

Either you override it, like you did, and then that will be returned, or it will use the default implementation, which is inherited from the Object class.