# Trying to loop through an array within an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print each part of my noteArray (eg: 19, and then "D" as separate parts) But by using a For loop I get an a mumble up print message for each line. The "processNotes(noteArray)" method is how I want my output to look.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public class question2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Note[] noteArray = new Note[5];
    noteArray[0] = new Note(19, "D");
    noteArray[1] = new Note(10, "C");
    noteArray[2] = new Note(23, "F");
    noteArray[3] = new Note(20, "B");
    noteArray[4] = new Note(32, "C");
    processNotes(noteArray);
    for(Note i : noteArray){
        System.out.println(i);
        }
}
private static void playNote() {
    int numberDuration = Note.getduration();
    String letterPitch = Note.getpitch();
    System.out.println("The note "+ letterPitch +" is played for "+ 
numberDuration +" seconds.");
    return;
}
public static void processNotes(Note[] notes) {
    playNote();
}
}
class Note
{
private static String pitch;
private static int duration;
public Note(int duration, String pitch) {
    this.pitch = "C";
    this.duration = 10;
}
public static int getduration() {
    return duration;
}
public void setduration(int duration) {
    Note.duration = duration;
}
public static String getpitch() {
    return pitch;
}
public void setpitch(String pitch) {
    Note.pitch = pitch;
}
}
```

EDIT:

Output I would like:
    The note C is played for 10 seconds.

Output of arrays I get:

```
Note@6d06d69c
Note@7852e922
Note@4e25154f
Note@70dea4e
Note@5c647e05
```

Comment: override toString in Note class

Comment: It would be useful to see what you got and what you want in the question. Use the edit link below your question to add it.

Answer (score 3):

You have two possibility.

First, override your toString() method so that it prints your notes as you want when you `System.out.println()`.

Second, you can in your loop, instead of printing the note :

```
for(Note i : noteArray){
    System.out.println(i.getPitch());
    System.out.println(i.getDuration());
}
```

Comment: Absolutely no problem, and thanks for taking the time to explain it !

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your Note class:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Duration = " + duration + ", pitch = " + pitch;
}
```

[Demo](https://www.ideone.com/AojCwR)

---

From [object.toString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

You can override this method for a more meaningful output.

Suggested further read: [The connection between 'System.out.println()' and 'toString()' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318996/the-connection-between-system-out-println-and-tostring-in-java)

Comment: This is exactly what I am after! However, how would I get it to get and set the duration and pitch to multiple different values by looping it through the noteArray for the Note class?

Comment: You can use `setduration` and `setpitch`.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I've tried putting a loop into the "setduration" part but I keep having trouble.

Comment: @Tipzil You need to drop `static` from many places and fix the contructor of Note class. See [working demo here](https://www.ideone.com/bHFoGz)

Answer (score 1):

You can just override toString method of the Note class, as sysout implicitly call toString.