# How the toString() is working with Predicate in the following program

Tags: java-8, tostring, predicate

Can anybody please explain how the toString() function is working with this Predicate. I understood the lambda expression but how the toString() function is called.

```
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.*;
class Demo{
public static void main(String arv[]){
    HashSet <Employee> hs = new HashSet<>();
    hs.add(new Employee("A",40000,25,"CSE"));
    hs.add(new Employee("B",50000,26,"CSE"));
    hs.add(new Employee("C",54000,30,"ECEadsa"));
    hs.add(new Employee("D",45000,25,"ECE"));
    hs.add(new Employee("E",60000,32,"CSE"));
    Predicate <Employee> emp = t -> t.salary > 50000;
    Predicate <Employee> emp1 = emp.and( t -> t.department.length()>5);
    for(Employee e: hs)
    if (emp1.test(e))
    System.out.println(e);
                                     }
         }
class Employee{
   String name;
   double salary;
   int age;
   String department;
   Employee(String n, double s, int a, String d){
   name = n;
   salary = s;
   age = a;
   department = d;
              }
public String toString(){
   return " name = "+name+" salary = "+salary+" age = "+age+" department = "+department;
                        }
               }
```

Output:
name = C salary = 54000.0 age = 30 department = ECEadsa

Comment: `System.out.println(e);` calls `toString()` for `e`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The connection between 'System.out.println()' and 'toString()' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318996/the-connection-between-system-out-println-and-tostring-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You have added code for printing Employee, **When ever you print any object toString() method is called** for that class if present else toString of parent is called

> ```
>   for(Employee e: hs)
>     if (emp1.test(e))
>     System.out.println(e);
>               }
>          }
> ```

For Employee  with department.length() > 5 printing logic System.out.println(e); is called

Answer (score 0):

In the PrintStream class the println(Object x) method uses String.valueOf(x), which invokes the toString() of the object.
If you had not overwritten the toString() method, you would use the default implementation of the Object class.