# How to print double arraylist of double arraylist

Tags: java

I have arraylist that contains a matrix of multiple lines of double values called (array1). When I add array1 to another arraylist called (array) and print the last one, I got the outputs in one line rather than multiple lines.

Here is the code:

```
List<Double> array=  new ArrayList<Double>();
for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    List<Double> array1=  new ArrayList<Double>();
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        int value =Mat[r][c];
        x[c] = value;
        array1.add(x[c]);
    }
    System.out.println(array1+" ");
    array.addAll(array1);
}  
System.out.println("the array" +  array);
```

Comment: What is incrementing `r`?

Comment: You use a double for loop to add data to to each field. You can also use the double for loop to print out each value by its own.

Comment: sorry I updated@DevilsHnd

Comment: I have used and still got the result in one line @M.Dan

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you add the output you get and the one you expect from a small input matrix

Comment: @sally you need to print the value in each step not the object: change e.g. System.out.println(array1+" "); to System.out.println(array1[r])

Comment: @M.Dan - **array1** is not an array. It's a List Interface and therefore the usage would be `array1.get(r)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not familiar wiht the usage of println.
The method println() outputs a string to your commandline and adds a newline. If you pass in an object which is not null, the object's toString() method will be called.

For further information read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319217/9461640

So you are getting a oneliner as the toString() of your List array will basically print everything it holds into one single string.

If you want to print a line for each element of the array you have to iterate over it.
This can be accomplished in many ways.

One way would be:

```
for (ArrayList<double> insideArray : array) {
    System.out.println(insideArray);
}
```

Have a look here for more iteration examples: https://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/

Answer (score 0):

That's the nature of the beast. If you ask the **Scanner#println()** method to print an ArrayList or List Interface then it will do so all in one line just the same as it would with a double[] Array using:

```
String.out.println(Arrays.toString(myDoubleArray));
```

To acquire a specific element from an ArrayList or a List Interface you would need to use:

```
array.get(someIndexValue);
          OR
array1.get(someIndexValue);
```

I think what you may want to do is move the print code line into your inner **for** loop:

```
List<Double> array=  new ArrayList<Double>();
for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    List<Double> array1=  new ArrayList<Double>();
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        int value =Mat[r][c];
        x[c] = value;
        array1.add(x[c]);
        System.out.println(array1.get(r));
    }
    array.addAll(array1);
}
```

but then again, you would just be better off printing **x[c]** if this is what you're trying to do.

If what you want is to display the elements within **array1** after the inner **for** loop has completed filling it and before it is added to **array** then you will need to iterate through the collection:

```
List<Double> array=  new ArrayList<Double>();
for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    List<Double> array1=  new ArrayList<Double>();
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        int value =Mat[r][c];
        x[c] = value;
        array1.add(x[c]);
        System.out.println(array1.get(r));
    }

    System.out.println("From Inner Loop:");
    for (int e = 0; e < array1.size(); e++) {
        System.out.println(array1.get(e));
    }

    array.addAll(array1);
}
```

If you want to print each element within the **array** list then you need to do the same thing with yet another loop: