# How to keep trailing 0s while converting a string to BigDecimal without exponent

Tags: java

I need to convert this two strings **"0.0000000"** and **"0.0000008"** to BigDecimal without losing trailing 0s.

I tried String.format

```java
String format = "%." + precision + "f";
BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(10, precision));
formattedAmount = amountValue.divide(divisor).setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
String str= String.format(format, formattedAmount);
System.out.println(str);
BigDecimal strb = new BigDecimal(str);
System.out.println(strb);
```

I am expecting these two strings **"0.0000000"** and **"0.0000008"** to be returned as BigDecimal without exponent like **0.0000000** and **0.0000008**. But i am getting **0E-7** and **8E-7**.
**I need 0.0000000 and 0.0000008 as BigDecimal not as String.**

Comment: _"I am expecting these two strings"_ and _"as BigDecimal not as String"_ are opposing statements. Which is it you want?

Comment: What about `BigDecimal.doubleValue()`?

Comment: @Phil : I can achieve my desired output by using .plainString() method but this method will return String not BigDecimal. Like if you convert this string "1234.567890" to BigDecimal it will return you 1234.567890 but in case of "0.0000000" it is returning 0E-7 not 0.0000000. I hope you got what i need to say. Thank you.

Comment: `0.0000008` (BigDecimal, not String)  is exactly the same as `8E-7` (BigDecimal, not String) - if you *print* it or display it (GUI, console), you are getting a `String` representing that value, and that is different

Comment: @Amadan a word of caution, BigDecimal `0.0` and `0.00000` are not considered `equals` (in BigDecimal implementation, different scale), but `compareTo` returns `0` as being the same value

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: You are right, I was thinking of other languages' implementations.

Comment: @AashuY when you print bigDeciamal object in `System.out.println(...)` it also returns a string, since `.toString()` method will be called automatically. It is just question of output format. In any case the value of bigDecimal will be the same, no matter is there exponent or not

Comment: @DeHaar : BigDecimal.doubleValue() is making 0.0000000 as 0.0 and 0.0000008 as 8.0E-7. This is not what i am expecting. Thank you

Comment: Is there any way to instruct not to use exponent form while the below line get executed :**formattedAmount = amountValue.divide(divisor).setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);**

Comment: sure not. `formattedAmount`, despite its name, is not formatted, it is just a value (BigDecimal). It have to be *converted* to a string to be formatted (e.g. using `toString()`, `String.format()`, `DecimalFormat`, ...)

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to print BigDecimal in `System.out.println(strb)` the `toString()` method on `strb` object will be invoked. So the output in console is also **string**.

See more [The connection between 'System.out.println()' and 'toString()' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318996/the-connection-between-system-out-println-and-tostring-in-java)

So the only way to tell the java not to use exponent here `System.out.println(strb)` is to change `toString()` method. You can't change it directly, but you could create your own class that extends `BigDecimal` and override `toString()` method you need. Obviously it doesn't make sense.. just use [`toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) method. From java doc:

> return a string representation of this {@code BigDecimal} without an exponent field.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no matter how you output the value of a `BigDecimal`, it stays the same in an instance of it (as long as you don't do calculations on it).

However, the output may differ a lot.
Here are the methods `BigDecimal` is offering

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String zero = "0.0000000";
    String zeroDotsEight = "0.0000008";

    BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal(zero);
    BigDecimal zE = new BigDecimal(zeroDotsEight);

    // play around with the precision and have a look at the output
    int precision = 7;

    System.out.println("String:\t\t\t\t\t" + zero);
    System.out.println("BigDecimal:\t\t\t\t" + z.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN));
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.toString():\t\t\t"
            + z.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).toString());
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.toPlainString():\t\t"
            + z.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).toPlainString());
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.toEngineeringString():\t"
            + z.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).toEngineeringString());
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.doubleValue():\t\t"
            + z.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).doubleValue());

    System.out.println("————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————");

    System.out.println("String:\t\t\t\t\t" + zeroDotsEight);
    System.out.println("BigDecimal:\t\t\t\t" + zE.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN));
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.toString():\t\t\t"
            + zE.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).toString());
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.toPlainString():\t\t"
            + zE.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).toPlainString());
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.toEngineeringString():\t"
            + zE.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).toEngineeringString());
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.doubleValue():\t\t"
            + zE.setScale(precision, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).doubleValue());
}
```

and this is the output on my system

```
String:                             0.0000000
BigDecimal:                         0E-7
BigDecimal.toString():              0E-7
BigDecimal.toPlainString():         0.0000000
BigDecimal.toEngineeringString():   0.0E-6
BigDecimal.doubleValue():           0.0
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
String:                             0.0000008
BigDecimal:                         8E-7
BigDecimal.toString():              8E-7
BigDecimal.toPlainString():         0.0000008
BigDecimal.toEngineeringString():   800E-9
BigDecimal.doubleValue():           8.0E-7
```

As you can see, @Ruslan is right. You have to create your own class or use `toPlainString()` in order to keep the format and not lose any trailing zeros (which should only matter for the human eye, but I even doubt they really do).
In addition, you were right as well when you commented that `doubleValue()` is not the way to go.

As stated in the only code comment, play around with the precision, maybe calculate some values before printing and/or storing the results in variables.