# Why doesn't this method give any output?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of objects, and I want to search in that ArrayList keywords, but searching in a specific field of the class. I have the class `Product`, the `ArrayList` `products` and I tried this:

```
public static void Search (String keywords){
    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++){
        if (products.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(keywords.toLowerCase())){
            System.out.println(products.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

"Keywords" is a string to search for.
The class Product is this:

```
 public class Product {

    String title;
    ImageIcon image;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Product(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Product{" + "title=" + title + '}';
   }
```

I also instanciated some objets of Product, inside a products ArrayList:

`ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();`

```
products.add(new Product("Car"));
products.add(new Product("House"));
products.add(new Product("Phone"));
```

And I call the function:

```
    Search("car");
```

When I call the method "Search", no output is printed. Why? Thanks!

EDIT: the "toString" method is included in the Product class.

Comment: `getTitle` is not `getTitulo`.. what does your code really look like? (I am not a downvoter)

Comment: I corrected it, it was because it was programmed in spanish and I translated it to post it here

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How are your `Product` instances initialized, with what title? What does `keywords` contain? Do those match as you expected?

Comment: Okay, looks better. Also some input data (what is `keyword`, what are in `products`) and expected output would help. Have you tried to debug and unit-test your code?

Comment: `keywords` sounds like a sequence of keywords, which I wouldn't expect the title of a single element of your `products` list to contain. Anyway it seems to me it would be easier for you to try using your IDE's debugger than to provide all the additional informations we'd need to help you

Comment: You have a `toString()` method, right? Can you add this method to your question?

Comment: I can run your code like your expect. Double check if you have a problem in your Main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are not getting any output, it means `contains` returns `false`.
2. A cleaner way is to use enhanced `for` loop.
3. You should follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `Search` should be `search` as per the naming convention.
4. You should check the variables for `null` before performing any operation on them.
5. You do not need to call `toString()` explicitly inside `System.out.println` as it is implicitly called.

```
public static void search(String keyword) {
    for (Product product : products) {
        if (keyword != null && product != null && product.getTitle() != null
                && product.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println(product);
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Product {
    String title;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public Product(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" + "title=" + title + '}';
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new Product("Car"));
        products.add(new Product("House"));
        products.add(new Product("Phone"));
        search("car", products);
    }

    public static void search(String keyword, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        for (Product product : products) {
            if (keyword != null && product != null && product.getTitle() != null
                    && product.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println(product);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Product{title=Car}
```

Comment: He/She has a method `toString()` so you are trying to _**print a class**_ in this line;
`System.out.println(product);`

Comment: I tried that piece of code but it still doesn't print anything. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Matrix4290 - I'm doing the correct thing. It's because he has overridden the method, `toString`, his overridden `toString` will be implicitly called. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318996/the-connection-between-system-out-println-and-tostring-in-java) to learn more about it. Feel free to let me know if you need any further help in understanding this concept.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!! Would the method work without giving the ArrayList as a parameter? If not, why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Would the method work without giving the ArrayList as a parameter? If not, why?` - if you have `ArrayList<Product> products` as an instance variable and a method to add products to it, and the method, `search` inside the class, `Product` then you do not need to pass `products` to `search`. I hope, you will be able to do it if you try. Feel free to let me know in case you face any issue.